# Activity cannot be visibly started by BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a service that has to start a certain Activity. I created a BroadcastReceiver and it calls the Activity (it is *not* the main activity) by this code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, DataActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    Log.w("DEBUG","Activity started. Context: "+context.getClass().toString());
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

I also set in the manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

I was in the phone's menu and waited for the activity to show. Nothing happened. When I changed to my app, the activity became visible and *resumed*. That's a problem, I have to make the activity immediately visible when the BroadcastReceiver starts it.

Any idea what to try?

Comment: did you bind your service to the application? This should work already as it is.

Comment: I did not bind it as my service should still be running when the app was killed.

Comment: i got an app, where i have a service that holds/handles a buttonClickReceiver, which can start a custom-activity. is that what you are looking for? then i would past some code here.

Comment: My goal is simple: my service should keep running regardless of the main app. However when the service start the activity, it should pop up immediately and not stay in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a broadcast is weak.

The activity has to be ***directly*** started from inside the service.

Instead of this:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
     broadcastIntent.setAction(DataBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
     broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
     sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Use this in the service:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DataActivity.class);
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```